# El filtrado con 'pre_get_posts' no me funciona

Tags: php

He buscado bastante y no encuentro respuesta. Alguien me pudiera decir que estoy haciendo mal, el filtrado no funciona, la consulta no da ningún producto. No hay ninguna complejidad en ese filtrado, honestamente no sé qué no funciona, cualquier ayuda será útil, Gracias por adelantado.

```
function qs_pre_get_posts($query) {

    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ){
       return;
    }

    if ( !is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) ){
       return;
    }

    $meta_query[] = array( 'key' => 'post_title', 'value' => 'abc', 'compare' => 'LIKE' );

    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'qs_pre_get_posts', 1 );
```

Comment: Me parece que te está faltando obtener la `$meta_query` original, pon primero esto: `$meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');` y luego el resto: `$meta_query[] = array( ... )`

Comment: Gracias Cedano, pero por no funciono, en algún momento lo había probado y frente a tu sugerencia lo intente nuevamente y nada.
De hecho, si elimino:

`add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'qs_pre_get_posts', 1 );`

Muestra todos los productos.

Si solo elimino las líneas:

`$meta_query[] = array( 'key' => 'post_title', 'value' => 'abc', 'compare' => 'LIKE' );`
`$query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );`

Entonces muestra todos los productos. Esto significa que se ejecuta el filtro, pero no encuentra coincidencias usando el “LIKE”.

Comment: Pero, una pregunta tonta: ¿realmente tienes `post_title` con el valor `abc`? ¿Podrías mostrar algún ejemplo de salida cuando dices que los muestra todos?

Comment: Agregue una respuesta que no es respuesta, es solo para ponerte todo lo que me has pedido, soy nuevo en stackoverflow y no sé de qué otra forma ponerte el ejemplo.

Comment: Puedes pulsar en [edit]  para agregar nuevos datos en la pregunta. El área de *Respuestas*  es para respuestas exclusivamente. Por otra parte, si estás buscando por el título del post, no sé por qué usas meta_query para esto ¿? Sugiero que intentes una búsqueda basada en el parámetro `s`, por ejemplo, como se indica en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39127132/5587982).

Comment: El tema es que necesito hacer una consulta más especifica que involucra más cosas y el parámetro “s” no es útil. La información a buscar y la forma de buscar se obtienen por URL en diferentes variables y entonces hay que preparar la consulta antes que se ejecute esta. Según WP, esta es la forma correcta de modificar una. Ejemplo: la página de productos ya tiene una consulta predefinida y mostrará todos los productos, si cambiamos la consulta usando `add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'qs_pre_get_posts', 1 );` podemos filtrarla y el resto debe continuar correctamente. Continua....

Comment: El ejemplo que he puesto es solo para ilustrar el problema que tengo. Con `$meta_query[] = array( 'key' => 'post_title', 'value' => 'beanie', 'compare' => 'LIKE' );` la consulta debe entregar solo los productos que tienen en algún lugar del título ‘beanie’, o al menos que sea exactamente el título. Algo no estoy haciendo bien, y justamente necesito saber que está mal.

Comment: Entiendo... Agradecería ver un pequeño `var_dump` (dos o tres elementos solamente) del resultado que obtienes cuando sí se muestran datos. Me refiero al resultado en sí, no  a lo que muestras en la página en forma de HTML.

Comment: Justo en eso estaba haciendo ahora, ¿de cuál variable quieres ver?

Comment: $meta_query

array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(10) "post_title" ["value"]=> string(6) "beanie" ["compare"]=> string(4) "LIKE" } }

Comment: No hablo de `$meta_query` sino de los resultados. O sea, del resultado que usas para mostrar los datos, cuando devuelve resultados (segunda captura de pantalla de lo que aportaste como respuesta). En alguna parte manejas la respuesta para mostrar los datos  ¿no? (imagen, precio, etc).

Comment: Otra cosa que podrías intentar seria poner la key así: `'key' => 'title',`  ... No sé, en la documentación no veo ningún ejemplo en el que se use `meta_quey` para buscar posts por título.

Comment: Tienes razón, voy a mirar un par de cosas de la documentación y luego te cuento.

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/178492). Allí se introduce un argumento personalizado: `_meta_or_title` y dentro de él otro array con `meta_query`, me parece que es lo que estarías buscando.

Comment: Creo que efectivamente, yo estaba perdido en un campo de lechugas, la variable `$query` que recibe esta función está directamente relacionada con `WP_Query()` y creo que lo que estoy haciendo está mal. Evidentemente falta de conocimiento de mi parte, lo correcto es leeré un poco más, luego te cuento.

Comment: Hola Cedano, finalmente es lo que me decías. Aunque no me gusta mucho la forma en que lo hacen. En varios ejemplos lo que hacen es recuperar primero los ID mediante una consulta y luego filtran la consulta con esos ID usando `pre_get_posts`. Otra variante, creo mejor desde el punto de vista del consumo de recursos del servidor, es modificar el where usando el filtro `posts_where`. De cualquiera de las dos formas el resto del proceso después de la consulta continúan por si solo.Pondré estas dos soluciones por si alguien se encuentra en mi misma situación. Un millón de gracias Cedano.